# как правильно расположить элементы в соответствии с макетом?

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: фрагмент макета]

Доброго времени суток. Прошу помощи в реализации данного фрагмента макета. Я сделал через разбитие на два списка, но хотелось бы более лучший способ решения данной задачи. Своё решение прикреплю здесь

```css
.listWorks {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 99px;
}

.listWorks li {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}

.listWorks li:not(.workLong),
.listWorks a:not(.workLongLink) { max-height: 390px; }

.workLong, .workLongLink { max-height: 780px; }
```

```html
<ul class="listWorks">
   <li>
 <a href="#" class="hoverImg">
     <img src="img/work-photo1.jpeg" alt="">
   </a>
   </li>
   <li>
 <a href="#" class="hoverImg">
   <img src="img/work-photo2.jpeg" alt="">
 </a>
   </li>
   <li>
 <a href="#" class="hoverImg">
  <img src="img/work-photo5.jpeg" alt="">
 </a>
   </li>
   <li>
 <a href="#" class="hoverImg">
  <img src="img/work-photo6.jpeg" alt="">
   <span class="linkCaption montReg">creatively designed <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</span></span>
 </a>
   </li>
  </ul> 
  <ul class="listWorks">
   <li class="workLong">
 <a href="#" class="hoverImg workLongLink">
  <img src="img/work-photo3.jpeg" alt="">
 </a>
   </li>
   <li>
 <a href="#" class="hoverImg">
  <img src="img/work-photo4.jpeg" alt="">
 </a>
   </li>
   <li>
 <a href="#" class="hoverImg">
  <img src="img/work-photo7.jpeg" alt="">
 </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос свои попытки реализации (свой код)

Comment: Может вам посмотреть в сторону плагинов для реализации такой штуки? Например https://jquery-mosaic.tin.cat или https://masonry.desandro.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поддержка конечно плохая но смотрите :

Но ещё у Grid есть **grid-temlate-areas** на которой вот такие сетки как у вас вообще самое оно .. но читайте yandex или google и пользуйтесь но не навязчиво так как поддержка не очень у Grid

```css
.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 180px 250px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 250px 200px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.item1 {
  background: red;
}

.item2 {
  background: blue;
}

.item3 {
  background: pink;
}

.item4 {
  background: yellow;
}

.item5 {
  background: tomato;
}

.item6 {
  background: grey;
}

.item7 {
  background: violet;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 3/3;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item1">item1</div>
  <div class="item2">item2</div>
  <div class="item3">item3</div>
  <div class="item4">item4</div>
  <div class="item5">item5</div>
  <div class="item6">item6</div>
  <div class="item7">item7</div>
</div>
```

**смотреть на весь экран**