# Картинки разных размеров в ровный ряд

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать картинки(плитку) как на примере

Использую bootstrap 4. Мой код, до другого пока не додумался:

```
<div class="card-columns">
<div class="card">
<img src="images/2.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid yey">
</div>

<div class="card">
<img src="images/2.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid yey">
</div>

<div class="card">
<img src="images/2.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid yey">
</div>

<div class="card">
<img src="images/2.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid yey">
</div>

<div class="card">
<img src="images/4.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid yey">
</div>

<div class="card">
<img src="images/2.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid yey">
</div>

<div class="card">
<img src="images/2.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid yey">
</div>
</div>
```

Получается такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так? Почему последний квадрат не стал на пустое место. Как правильно написать код?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как правильно расположить элементы в соответствии с макетом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805069/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: Последний квадрат имеет такой же размер?

Comment: Да, у всех квадратов одинаковый размер по ширине, синий в 2 раза выше

Answer (score 6):

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col__item {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #f00;
}

.col__item_stretch {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col__item"></div>
    <div class="col__item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col__item"></div>
    <div class="col__item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col__item col__item_stretch"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col__item"></div>
    <div class="col__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```